# When i try to print out some unicode chars as hex in C, they all have the same value for some reason

Tags: c, printing, printf

So for some reason, all these UNICODE characters appear to have the same value when i print them out in C Does anyone have any idea why?

```
char input[8] = {'⺖', '⺓', '⺄', '⺑', '⻣', '⺽', '⻻', '⺽'};
for( i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    printf("Input number equivelents in hex %x, in int %i\nj", input[i], (int)input[i]);
}
```

This is what the UNICODE corresponds to in C#. in C they print out as 0x3f.

```
C#
        [0x00000000]    0x2e96 '⺖'  char
        [0x00000001]    0x2e93 '⺓'  char
        [0x00000002]    0x2e84 '⺄'  char
        [0x00000003]    0x2e91 '⺑'  char
        [0x00000004]    0x2ee3 '⻣'  char
        [0x00000005]    0x2ebd '⺽'  char
        [0x00000006]    0x2efb '⻻'  char
        [0x00000007]    0x2ebd '⺽'  char
```

Comment: `char` can't hold two-byte unicode characters. It's one byte in size.

Comment: Char can't hold a unicode char. Use wchar_t f.e.

Comment: the first byte must be the same for all of the unicode values thanks to visual studio.

Comment: Note that char in c# is unicode, in c it is not. You can compare char in c to an sbyte in c#.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - He used C# in order to validate his results in C.

Comment: C and C# are unrelated languages, and I don't see a C# tag anywhere. Would you also post comments about how things work in Perl, PHP, or JavaScript on a C question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to precede each constant with `L`:

```
wchar_t input[8] = {L'⺖', L'⺓', L'⺄', L'⺑', L'⻣', L'⺽', L'⻻', L'⺽'};
for( i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    printf("Hex: %x, Int: %i\n", input[i], (int)input[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need another data structure to hold those  characters, as one char (which is traditionally 8 bits, or 0x00 - 0xFF) cannot contain them.

Thus, use a data-structre like `int` or `short` to hold them, and use the `L` specifier before the literal:

```
int input[8] = { L'⺖', L'⺓', L'⺄', L'⺑', L'⻣', L'⺽', L'⻻', L'⺽' };
```

And your code will work properly.

Comment: Without the `L` prefix (see egrunin's answer) it's highly implementation-dependent whether this works...

Comment: @R.. hmm. Interesting, I use gcc/clang on a mac, so I never ran into this. But I did update my post.